# Disable authentication for HTTP OPTIONS method (preflight request)

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, http, apache-2.4, cors

One recurring problem with CORS is that the spec prescribes request headers get stripped from the preflight request (HTTP OPTIONS). However if the server requires authentication, this means the preflight request will fail (because the `Authorization` header does not get included) and it will not be able to receive the required `access-control-allow-origin` header.

The only way out seems to be to configure the server to not enforce authentication for HTTP OPTIONS requests. Is there any way in apache 2.4 that i can make `Require valid-user` conditional on the http method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can limit the scope of `Require valid-user` by using `Limit/LimitExcept` :

```
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
  Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

See [apache documentation on Limit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limit)