# Disable authentication for HTTP OPTIONS method (preflight request) in Nginx

Tags: nginx, cors

My problem is the exact same one as described here: [Disable authentication for HTTP OPTIONS method (preflight request)](https://serverfault.com/questions/684855/disable-authentication-for-http-options-method-preflight-request). I'm trying to use CORS and HTTP passwords at the same time. When the browser see an bounced OPTIONS (status code 401), for some reason it'll immediate check for the CORS headers (which will be absent) and reject the request.

Here's my config:

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:14000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Content-Type";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/admin.htpasswd;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the solution I came up with. It insolves duplicating all the CORS add_header directives though.

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:14000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Content-Type";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
        add_header Content-Length 0;
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization, Content-Type";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
        return 200;
    }
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/admin.htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: If you use the headers_more module, you'll be able to avoid redundancy and configure this in more clean way: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b843bd579041188441f51a7805cf537e

Answer (score 4):

I found a cleaner solution which lets node manage the request:

Put the following configuration inside "location" and remove any auth_basic from server. This will work.

```
  location / {
    # Your node proxy configuration for example #

    # Make options requests work #
    limit_except OPTIONS {
      auth_basic "Restricted access zone";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pass/protected;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following information at [limit_except/if blocks problems](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2323), I'd suggest using `map`:

```
map $request_method $auth_basic_value {
    default "Restricted";
    "OPTIONS" "off";
}


location / {
        auth_basic $auth_basic_value;
}
```

Keep in mind, that if you have some `try_files` in that location, that may rewrite the query to another location, then you may also need to set `auth_basic $auth_basic_value`.

Comment: Submitted an [edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/525801) for your solution, which does work (after the edit), and is by far the simplest I've seen.